# Authentication does not redirect back to my Android App in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, azure-mobile-services

I'm writing a simple Xamarin.Forms app with Azure Mobile Apps on the backend. I am trying to implement simple server-flow authentication, but it's not working. I've tried following instructions in [this Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-users), [this Github thread](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-client/issues/341#issuecomment-308337440), and [this online book](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter2/enterprise/), but to no avail.

When I invoke the login code, I am taken to the Azure login page in a webview. After putting in my credentials, the browser directs back to what appears to be the expected URL, but I stay in the browser with an error message.

lookatmetestingthisurischeme://easyauth.callback/#authorization_code=QHcJvRN1IXxC9QGWH_gibberish_continues_forever...

[image]

Azure Mobile Apps authentication settings: 
[image]

Android Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.MyApp">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" />
    <application android:label="MyApp.Android"></application>
  <activity android:name="com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.authentication.RedirectUrlActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:noHistory="true">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
      <data android:scheme="lookatmetestingthisurischeme" android:host="easyauth.callback" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
</manifest>
```

My login implementation in the Android project

```
await client.LoginAsync(_context, MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.WindowsAzureActiveDirectory, 
"lookatmetestingthisurischeme");
```

Bonus points if you can tell me how to get this working on UWP. In UWP, the browser opens, I get to log in, and I'm never redirected back to my app.

Comment: Did you find a solution?  It looks this doesnt work anymore

Comment: Have you found a solution ?

Comment: Did you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the "activity..." node is INSIDE the "application..." node.  Looks like in your manifest it's sitting after it.  Should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.whatever">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />
    <application android:label="myapp.Client.Android">
      <activity android:name="com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.authentication.RedirectUrlActivity"
                 android:launchMode="singleTop" android:noHistory="true">
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
          <data android:scheme="myurlscheme" android:host="easyauth.callback" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```